# Do we say "The rat ran to and then under the ticket booth" or just "The rat ran under the ticket booth"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Look at this picture, a rat was at a distance from the ticket booth. The suddenly, the rat ran towards the booth and then sneaked under the booth.

[image]

The dictionary says

> [under](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/under_1?q=under) (prep) in, **to** or through a position that is below something
>
> Have you looked under the bed?
>
> She placed the ladder under (= just lower than) the window.
>
> The dog squeezed under the gate and ran into the road.

---

So, according to oxford dictionary, **under**: **to a position that is below something**

So, "**The rat ran under the booth**" can be replaced by "**The rat ran to a position that is below the booth**"

But saying that "**The rat ran under the booth**" may be confusing because people may think the rat just ran under the booth but not from a position outside the booth.

My question is

Do we say "**The rat ran to and then under the ticket booth**" or just "**The rat ran under the ticket booth**"?

Comment: There is no need to explain that the rat ran to the booth before disappearing under it; that's self-evident if it came from somewhere else. If it was already under there we would say something like "The rat was running about under the booth".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would anyone say the very wordy:

> The rat ran **to a position that is** below the booth
>   OR
>   The rat ran **to and then** under the ticket booth

when the sentence *below* does the job perfectly?

> The rat ran/was under the booth

The Oxford Learners' Dictionary says "a position that is below something" to ***define*** the preposition “under”.

That's not to say there is only one way to [eat an orange](http://etiquipedia.blogspot.com/2014/10/etiquette-and-eating-fruits-properly.html); some people peel oranges served on a fruit plate with a knife and fork, so there's nothing wrong with the OP's substitute sentences per se, they're unnecessarily fussy.

Comment: but people may think the rat ONLY ran under the booth the whole time, they may not think that the rat ran from a position outside the booth before it went under the booth.

Comment: @Tom I wouldn't worry,  the verb "run" implies a certain distance, and saying "under" the booth means it was not always under it,  the rat was elsewhere (outside).

Comment: @Tom As I said in my earlier comment, if the rat was already under the booth we would say that it 'was running about under it'.